# trouble getting node's text with php xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following html:

```
<div class="data">
    <p class="info">output</p>
     <p class="info">output2</p>
```

I am trying to get the text "output" with the following

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    

foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//div[@class='data']/p[1]") as $elt) {
    $output=$elt->wholeText;
}

echo $output;
```

its not working . I'm getting 2 errors:

```
Message: Undefined property: DOMElement::$wholeText
Message: Undefined variable: output
```

could anyone point me in thr right direction?

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Comment: Could you first point us to the direction of what "not working" means?

Comment: Your div isn't closed.

Comment: What about using `DOMXPath::query()` ?

Comment: The error message is telling you everything: there is no `wholeText` property. Is that surprising? Did you read the docs?

Comment: try `echo $elt[0], $elt[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this:**

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 

$elements = $xpath->query("*/div[@class='data']");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to $elements = $xpath->query("//div[@class='data']"); Thanks it works.